# AngularJS Satellizer - Redirect on 401

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

I'm using AngularJS with Satellizer. What I'm finding, is if I manually alter the token on the API side, so a call to /api/me fails, and returns a 401, the app is not automatically redirecting to /auth/login.

I was under the impression, that with the following code, any time a 401 is returned, the user would be redirected to the login page:

`$authProvider.httpInterceptor = function() {
  return true;
};`

Anyone else run into the issue or have a work around? I can use a http interceptor, but I'm assuming there already should be one to handle this functionality.

Thanks,

James

Comment: You'll have to use your own custom interceptor for that, Satellizer doesn't handle the redirection part.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now. Then what's the config value used for? Just global usage of adding the token to all header request?

Comment: Roger! Thanks for clearing that all up.